# Add IR (infrared) remote control to simple audio amp?

Tags: audio, integrated-circuit, infrared, power-amplifier

is it possible to add some kind of a remote control receiver to a basic audio amp board that only has a manual volume knob?
The IC chip in the amp board is a TDA7498. A general view of the board is in the image[amp board](https://www.dhresource.com/600x600/f2/albu/g4/M01/24/35/rBVaEFnMpPKAE_AqAAHjwL2mI4w749.jpg)

Comment: Not easily.   You'd need an MCU to decode the remote commands, then then either find a place where you can control volume with an analog level, find a sufficiently wide-range digipot to insert, or even add a servomotor to move the volume knob - a feature actually seen on some stereos.

Comment: thanks a lot for the comment/ info Chris, I'll look into the mcu and digipot sugestin. Yeah I considered the servomotor but would be nice if I could manage a more electronic (than mecanical?) solution